# How to get date of a week before from the current system time in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a dropdown box where i select duration. if i select 1 week, i have to retrieve data for the past one week from the Mysql database. i do this with the help of the following query.

```
 SELECT * FROM rpt_machine_log WHERE (timestamp between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL $interval) and now())
```

when i select two weeks, i have to get two result sets, one contains the data of the current week, which can be done with the above query, i also want result set which contains the data for a week before the current week.

similarly, if i select 3 weeks, i should get 3 result set containing data for last 3 weeks, each week as separate result set.

I want to achieve this situation without changing the query, i just want to pass the date range to the query to get the result. Hence i need to fetch the end date for each week from the current system time.

**EDITED**
**EXPLAINED THE SITUATION WITH EXAMPLE:**

if the current day is Tuesday and date is 4-12-2012, when i select 3 weeks, i want record set between these days. 27-11-2012 to 4-12-2012 as one week result set, 20-11-2012 to 27-11-2012 as second week result set and 13-11-2012 to 20-11-2012 as week three result set. is this possible from your query??

Answer (score 0):

I have executed a query where you can find the week_start_date and week_end_date for the given dates in your table.
I have created a sample table for the same

```
create table tbl(
  orderid int(10),
  dt date);

insert into tbl values(1,'2012-12-04');

insert into tbl values(2,'2012-11-27');

insert into tbl values(3,'2012-11-20');

SELECT orderid,dt, 
 DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(dt)) DAY) week_start,
   DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(dt)) DAY) week_end
FROM tbl 
WHERE (dt between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 3 WEEK) and now())
group by week_start,week_end
order by week_start,week_end;
```

Hope this help to group the date o/p(s)

Comment: I don't want the exact start date and end date of the week. What i want is, suppose, if the current day is Tuesday and date is `4-12-2012`, when i select `3 weeks`, i want record set between these days. `27-11-2012 to 4-12-2012` as one week result set, `20-11-2012 to 27-11-2012` as second week result set and `13-11-2012 to 20-11-2012` as week three result set. is this possible from your query??